How to check if current user can listen on a privileged port?
Before starting a Java program I would like to run a script to check if the process will be able to listen on port 443. This script should try to listen to the port, if it is able to then close the port and return success else return failure.
I know I can do it with a combination of nc -l 443 and nc -q 0 localhost 443  < /dev/null. If the first command fails then I know the user cannot listen to the port, if it succeeds (i.e. does not return immediately) then the next one will close it.
But netcat no longer seems to be included in the default SuSE 15 and I would prefer not to have to install it.
I am thinking to use openssl s_server -port 443 -nocert & and kill -9 $! to decide if it exited.
Are there are any default distribution tools I can use where I can simply do check_port_listen 443 which can exist immediately indicating whether the port could be listened on?
